# What are the steps in installing the EV3 block developer Kit?

Tags: ev3

I've downloaded the block developer kit.  How do I incorporated into my Mindstorms software?

Comment: According to the download page, all the instructions are included in the kit. Have you check around the installation to see if there are any `readme.txt` files or HTML/PDF documents included?